# PHP and Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, sql

What I have is a drop down of the available rooms from a database. Like Classroom 1, followed by the maximum capacity in it so it looks like this, Classroom 1(28), Classroom 2(30) so on and so forth. Above this drop down list is a text box to enter the number of students enrolling so you can key in any number.

My question is, how do I eliminate the classrooms that do not fit the number keyed in the text box. So example I key in 30 and when i click the drop down list Classroom 1(28) isn't there anymore, instead Classroom 2(30) is listed.

Comment: That is a very generic question which shows that you need to read about AJAX.

Answer (score 3):

First you need an event on the textbox that is triggered when its text changes.

Then you need to loop through each option.  If the textbox value is greater than the parsed out classrom size value, you hide the option.

Jquery will be useful here.

In my opinion this is not an SQL or ajax problem.  You want to fetch all the existing classrooms and have them available as selections, and then filter the selections based on what the user types in a textbox.

jquery would look something like this

```
$('#Count_textbox').change(function(event)
{
  var countValue=$(this).val();

  //loops through each option
  $('#classroom_select').find('option').each(function(index)
  {
     //write parseOutValue to get the value out of the string of text
     var classroomValue=parseOutValue($(this).text());

     if( countValue > classroomValue )
     {
        $(this).attr("disabled","disabled");

     }
     else
     {
        $(this).attr("disabled","");
     }
  }
});
```

Comment: An alternative way to looping through the entries client side would be to send an AJAX request with the typed number to the server which invokes a php method which queries the DB for rooms big enough and sends the new selection back.

Comment: I do have jquery however I am not sure how to show let me show you the codes.

$roomarray = mysql_query("SELECT *
FROM(SELECT *,CASE
WHEN type = 'Classroom' THEN 1
WHEN type = 'Computer laboratory' THEN 2
WHEN type = 'Lecture Hall' THEN 3
WHEN type = 'Auditorium' THEN 4
END AS ClassTypeValue
FROM rooms
) t
ORDER BY ClassTypeValue, maxppl, roomID");
echo "<select id = \"room\">";
while ($rooms = mysql_fetch_array($roomarray))

Comment: { ?>
<option value=<?php echo $rooms['roomID']; ?> id=<?php echo $rooms['roomID']; ?>><?php echo $rooms['type']; echo "&nbsp;"; echo $rooms['roomID']; echo "&nbsp;("; echo $rooms['maxppl']; echo ")"; ?></option>
<?php
}

Comment: Thx Matt for you answer it is greatly appreciated, although you explained my situation, it is still not possible to hide a list down option based on the value that is entered in the text area from a prev. text field.

Comment: edited, however, this way the options are still visible.  Hiding them completey either requires more trickery, or an easy way that I don't know about.